# Pascal Triangle in Gui

Tags: java

Hello can you help me how to print the pascal triangle in JTextArea? The output is printing in general output. This is my constructor.

```
public static int ComputePascal(int rows) {



    for(int i =0;i<rows;i++) {

        int number = 1;

        System.out.format("%"+(rows-i)*2+"s","");

        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {

             System.out.format("%4d",number);

             number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);
               }

        System.out.println();

   }
   return rows;


}
```

this is my ActionListener

```
if(e.getSource()==b2){
String dee = f1.getText();
int dev = Integer.parseInt(dee);
int hard =  ComputePascal(dev);
String ans = String.valueOf(hard);
area.setText(ans);
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but your Question confuses, like you see in the answers: It is not comletely clear what you want. This could be 3 things: 1. print your output to an textArea? 2. format your output? 3. Both?

Comment: print my output in a textarea sir

Comment: ok you have to replace `System.out` with `textArea.append` as far as I know (you have to define it before)

Comment: @Zorian like this sir? textArea.append.println() or textArea.append()?

Comment: `textArea.append("Hello World");` and replace "Hello World" with the text and variable you want to print out

Comment: @zorian sir if i would like to format my output how?

Comment: I told you that I'm not an expert.... i don't know if it works etc, eg you have to wait for another to answer you or post a new clear question where you ask for: `JTextArea append and format string` or so

Comment: Thank you very much sir Zorian...:)

Comment: np I try my best to help because when I need help, I'm glad if someone helps me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in Java so correct me if I'm wrong, but I would suggest to create a JTextArea and then pass the line that is printed to the System.out to this JTextArea

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
//your code here
//add this instead of System.out with your own output in the ()
textArea.append("Pascal Triangle: " + number);
```

Comment: sir it will print the pascal triangle straight not a triangle

Comment: @GoranReymundo so the I missunderstand your question, because you asked for an output in a JTextArea instead of Console and if I wasn't clear enough, you shold use only the `textArea.append();` and fill it with your printout code to get the data to the JTextArea

Comment: sir i would like to call the constructor ComputePascal() by using an ActionListener..

Comment: if(e.getSource()==b2){
      this is my action Listener sir                                                                                         String dee = f1.getText();
  int dev = Integer.parseInt(dee);
  int hard =  ComputePascal(dev);
  String ans = String.valueOf(hard);
  area.setText(ans);

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do :

- Create a [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) that will contain the [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).
- Create and **add** the JtextArea to the frame.
- Setting the JTextArea with the string containing your values.

To help you in the use of swing api : [Getting started with swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html)